# Initialize a const array in compile time with a template-based length

Tags: c++, templates, template-meta-programming

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Programmatically create static arrays at compile time in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2978259/programmatically-create-static-arrays-at-compile-time-in-c)

Is it possible to initialize the following array in compile time?

```
template<int n> void
foo()
{
    static int pairs[2*n]; // = {0,0, 1,1, ..., n-1,n-1}
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
         pairs[2*i] = pairs[2*i+1] = i;
    }

    do_something_with_pairs(pairs);
}
```

(I use Clang on Xcode 4.5 so C++11 is OK)

Comment: the loop uses indices beyond the end of the array => **Undefined Behavior**.

Comment: Sorry, I fixed that now.

Comment: I'm wondering how many people have put their work aside and trying hard to solve this. This is a very good question. But I'm giving up.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know it's not possible to *extend* an array initializer, and that rules out a recursive template based solution as a means to generate static initialization data.

However, you can do the simple thing of having a static array with as many data points as you will ever use. This can be generated by a simple script. Or e.g. by the Boost preprocessor library.

Then you can just use a pointer to that array.