# Concatenate C Strings in one line without define

Tags: c++, constexpr, c-strings

Is there a C++ way of concatenating two constexpr C-strings at compile time? I know how to do it in C with defines, but would really rather have the scope reduction and explicit type system of C++. My primary goal is to have a nice way of concatenating strings at compile time in one line.

Here's an example of what does work in the way I don't want:

```
#define STR1 "foo"
#define STR2 "blah"
#define CONCATED STR1 STR2
```

Here's an example of what doesn't work in the way I do want:

```
constexpr const char *str1 = "foo";
constexpr const char *str2 = "blah";
constexpr const char *concated = str1 str2;
```

Comment: This answer seems to be in the right direction: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2978259/programmatically-create-static-arrays-at-compile-time-in-c

My template foo doesn't seem to be up to snuff, though. My attempt to use constexpr functions has not led to the answer yet, either.

Answer (score 1):

It can only be done at compile time with string literals.

```
 constexpr const char concatenated[] = "foo" "blah";
```

This is the effect achieved by your `CONCATED` macro (in fact, it is literally how the preprocessor expands usage of that macro).

If you want to concatenate named variables, then it is not possible to satisfy your requirement(s) of doing concatenation at compile time avoiding use of heap or stack.

The two obvious choices are to allocate enough memory to hold the result and then use `strcat()`, or to use the `std::string` type.   Both of these involve using heap or stack (depending on how you allocate memory, and how the allocator you choose for `std::string` works) and both do the concatenation at run time.

Comment: It's NOT compiler dependent. `& "foo" "blah"` is guaranteed to remain valid for the life of your program, which precludes stack allocation.

Comment: You're mixing concepts, MSalters.  The notion of stack, itself, has nothing to do with lifetime of a string literal.

Comment: I agree with that comment. But you said in the answer that the string literal `"foo" "blah"` may use the stack, depending on the compiler. That part of the answer is incorrect. The lifetime of a stack frame is only the duration of a function invocation, but the lifetime of a string literal is the whole duration of the process.

Comment: You're misinterpreting completely, MSalters.  In any event, I'm removing the sentence completely, since you won't let it go, and are just making irrelevant comments.

Comment: No template magicks to save me the effort? No hidden C++11 features? I'm reduced to poorly typed and scoped C methods?
I was thinking something like this might work, with issues with the null terminators, but haven't figured it out yet:

`constexpr const char str1[] = "foo";
constexpr const char str2[] = "blah";

template <const char s1[], const char s2[]>
struct constconcat {
 static constexpr const char p1[sizeof(s1)] = s1;
 static constexpr const char p2[sizeof(s2)] = s2;
};`

Comment: C strings are a feature with a number of anomalies inherited from (well, you know) C.